# Grid search using talos: passing a list of inputs error

Tags: machine-learning, keras, data-science, grid-search, talos

I am using keras functional API.
I'm trying to pass in a list of inputs.
I tried to follow this [issue](https://github.com/autonomio/talos/issues/132):

But I'm still getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'max'
```

This is my current model:

```
def create_model(x_train,y_train, parameters): 

# Multiple Inputs


# 1st input model
frame1 = Input(shape=(9216,))
hidden1 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(frame1)
hidden1= Dropout(0.2)(hidden1)
hidden1 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(hidden1)
#hidden1 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(hidden1)
output1 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(hidden1) 

# 2nd input model
frame2 = Input(shape=(9216,))
hidden2 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(frame2)
hidden1= Dropout(0.2)(hidden2)
hidden2 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(hidden2)
#hidden2 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(hidden2)
output2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(hidden2) 

model = Model(inputs=[x1, x2], 
              outputs=[output1, output2])

#Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])

history = model.fit(model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train, 
                              validation_split=0.2,
                              batch_size=parameters['batch_size'],
                              shuffle=False,
                              epochs=20,
                              verbose=1))

return history, model 

# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
```

My parameters for the grid search are:

```
parameters = {'batch_size': [10,20]}
```

I get the error when I run this:

```
import talos as ta
t = ta.Scan([train1,train2], 
            [y1,y2],
            params=p,
            model=model)  

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'max'
```

Note that my train1, train2 are numpy arrays with 9216 values. (96x96 image)

Answer (score 0):

I take it you solved this? If not it is because talos expects the `x` and `y` to be numpy arrays. If they are numpy arrays it means talos can call `max()` on them, whereas you cannot call `max()` on a list, which is what you have supplied to `.Scan()`.